# Return row per key based on precedence in Oracle's SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have data as below. Some items have more then one type id.
I need to select only one from each id.

My condition is that

- if exists (type id of item == 1) select only that row;
- if not exists type id is 1 check if exists (type id of item == 2) select
  that row;
- if  not exists type id is 2 check if exists (type id of item == 3)
  select that row;

I don't need data that it's type id is different from 1,2,3

| id | name | type_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 23 | xx | 1 |
| 24 | yy | 1 |
| 24 | yy | 2 |
| 24 | yy | 3 |
| 25 | zz | 2 |
| 26 | qq | 2 |
| 26 | qq | 3 |
| 27 | ww | null |
| 28 | tt | 4 |
| 28 | rr | 5 |

Expected result

| id | name | type_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 23 | xx | 1 |
| 24 | yy | 1 |
| 25 | zz | 2 |
| 26 | qq | 2 |

Comment: What does "item" mean? Is it a synonym for "id"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by type_id) as seqnum
      from t
      where type_id in (1, 2, 3)
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Note:  This uses the fact that the types you are looking for are ordered.  If they are arbitrary, then you might need a `case` expression in the `order by`.  For instance, if you wanted the precedence as 2, 1, 3:

```
order by (case type_id when 2 then 1 when 1 then 2 when 3 then 3 end)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id,
       min(name) keep (dense_rank first order by type_id) as name,
       min(type_id) as type_id
from   table_name
where  type_id in (1, 2, 3)
group  by id
;
```